# bcc32c does not save in staticobjs folder

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

Rad Studio Rio 10.3.1, CLANG. I create a simple C++ package project for static and dynamic linking.

In previous versions of Rad Studio, for static, the OBJ files were saved in "staticobjs" folder.

See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/C%2B%2B_Object_File_(*.obj,_*.o)

Now, in Rio, this folder is not created and OBJ files (dynamic and static) are overwritten, creating a mess when instead of using 'build' I use 'make'.

Is it a bug? Do I miss something?